# Reactjs : TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, typeerror

Getting the subjected error , I have no clue on the reason for this, did lot of research in google but 
answers not working out for my case. Service is in Springboot and it is giving correct result with postman where as my react application it is failing. Any help will be appreciated. see my code..

```
getSites = () => {     
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/xyz/sites", {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:':'http://localhost:8080',
                'accept':'application/json',
                'content-type':'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    sites: response
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        return this.state.sites;
    }
```

And the response json in postman is..

```
[
    {
        "parkDimKey": "12345",
        "parkName": "Site 1"
    },
    {
        "parkDimKey": "67890",
        "parkName": "Site 2"
    }
]
```

Spring boot Service is..

```
@RestController
public class SiteDataController {

    @Autowired
    SiteDataDao siteDataDao;

    @RequestMapping("/sites")
    public List<SiteData> getSiteData(){
        return siteDataDao.getSiteData();
    }
}
```

And the main application..

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/xyz/sites").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, turns out to be a simple typo. I removed a colon symbol from header name and it worked:

`'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:':'http://localhost:8080',`

`'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'http://localhost:8080',`